# INSERT multiple data from a SINGLE SELECT Statement (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to Insert multiple data from a single select statement in SQL Server 2008.

(1) For the Select Statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAllDaysBetweenTwoDate
(
@StartDate DATETIME,    
@EndDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TOTALCount INT
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,-1,@StartDate)
Select  @TOTALCount= DATEDIFF(DD,@StartDate,@EndDate);

WITH d AS 
        (
          SELECT top (@TOTALCount) AllDays = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (ORDER BY object_id), REPLACE(@StartDate,'-',''))
          FROM sys.all_objects
        )
    SELECT AllDays From d
RETURN 
END
GO
```

-- With this code, I am able to get the dates between 2 dates, which is the StartDate and EndDate.

(2) I am trying to INSERT the dates into another table.

FOR EXAMPLE

```
@StartDate = 2013-11-05
@EndDate = 2013-11-08
```

The Result would be the ff:

```
2013-11-05,
2013-11-06,
2013-11-07,
2013-11-08
```

I want to insert these dates into another table.

How can I do that? Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: insert into table1 select stuff from table2

Comment: @Randy You're absolutely right, but I have a feeling this isn't what he's actually looking for.

Comment: I tried that already. It didn't work. As you can see, there would be a lot of data from the SELECT statement because the SELECT Statement is getting the dates between the 2 dates. It doesn't insert

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Yeah, I tried that already. But it didn't work. I just want to insert the results of my select statement into another table. Do you have an idea on how to do it? Please help me.

Comment: @user2612969, can you post your code that you tried for inserting data, insert statement can handle multiple rows if you use correct syntax.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tblAttendance2 (DateTimeIn, Leave) VALUES ((SELECT AllDays FROM d), 1)` @rs.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, Try `INSERT INTO tblAttendance2 (DateTimeIn, Leave) SELECT AllDays, 1 FROM d`

Comment: "1" is not from table d @rs.

Comment: @user2612969, it doesn't matter, 1 is constant value and you can return that as part of sql, did you try that?

Comment: yes. I already tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: @user2612969, it should work, check this [sample code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5af9/1)

Comment: @rs. The code below already worked. But I cannot insert "1" still

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable 
EXECUTE getAllDaysBetweenTwoDate @StartDate = '2013-11-05', @EndDate = '2013-11-08';
```

**EDIT:** (Insert with a '1' constant)

```
DECLARE @t table ([date] datetime)

INSERT INTO @t ([date])
EXECUTE getAllDaysBetweenTwoDate @StartDate = '2013-11-05', @EndDate = '2013-11-08';

INSERT INTO MyTable (DateColumn, Number1Column)
SELECT [date], '1' FROM @t
```

Comment: I shall try this. Thanks@ @wdosanjos

Comment: Hi. I tried this... but it didn't work. It said 'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXECUTE''

Comment: Hi!! This worked already. It inserted the dates (between start & end) in the other table, but I also want to insert "1" together with the date. ANy idea? Thaanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you are trying to insert constant value along with dates. Change your code to do this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAllDaysBetweenTwoDate
(
@StartDate DATETIME,    
@EndDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TOTALCount INT
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,-1,@StartDate)
Select  @TOTALCount= DATEDIFF(DD,@StartDate,@EndDate);

WITH d AS 
        (
          SELECT top (@TOTALCount) AllDays = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (ORDER BY object_id), REPLACE(@StartDate,'-',''))
          FROM sys.all_objects
        )
    SELECT AllDays, 1 As Leave From d
RETURN 
END

GO
```

Then do this

```
INSERT INTO tblAttendance2 (DateTimeIn, Leave) 
EXEC getAllDaysBetweenTwoDate 
   @StartDate = '2013-11-05', 
   @EndDate = '2013-11-08';
```

If you want to return user id try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAllDaysBetweenTwoDate
(
@StartDate DATETIME,    
@EndDate DATETIME,
@userid varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TOTALCount INT
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,-1,@StartDate)
Select  @TOTALCount= DATEDIFF(DD,@StartDate,@EndDate);

WITH d AS 
        (
          SELECT top (@TOTALCount) AllDays = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (ORDER BY object_id), REPLACE(@StartDate,'-',''))
          FROM sys.all_objects
        )
    SELECT AllDays, 1 As Leave, @userid As userId From d
RETURN 
END

GO
```

Then do this

```
INSERT INTO tblAttendance2 (DateTimeIn, Leave, UserId) 
EXEC getAllDaysBetweenTwoDate 
   @StartDate = '2013-11-05', 
   @EndDate = '2013-11-08',
   @UserId = 'xyz';
```

Comment: Additional question, what if I want to insert a USER ID along with that into tblAttendance2? how will I do it? @rs.

Comment: @user2612969, you can add userid as parameter and return that in your select statement, check my updated answer

Comment: Hi! This is working in SQL but it isn't working in Visual Studio. COuld you please assist me again? Thank you @rs. :(